# Dev express C# buttonedit

Tags: c#, devexpress

How can I disable only the textbox part of buttonedit in devExpress elements in C#? I want to save three dots.

Comment: What have you tried? See [ask]. The idea is you show and tell us what you want to do and what you have tried, and tell us the problem you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

To disable text editing, you can set the [TextEditStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemButtonEdit.TextEditStyle.property) property to **DisableTextEditor**. If it's necessary, you can customize text appearance via the **Appearance** property.